# Listening for downloads from browser/getting name of downloaded file

Tags: java, android, browser, download, listener

Is there any way to listen for/detect a file being downloaded in Android? Also, can I programmatically get the name of the downloading file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a BroadcastReceiver (After api 9). Like this:

```
  BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                Query query = new Query();
                query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = c
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                            .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        String uriString = c
                                .getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

[HERE](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/) is the complete sample. Take a look and if you don't understand something just ask.

Comment: Is there any way to intercept the download before it completes?

Comment: Would there be any way to manipulate the solution using DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING while including the receiver in the Manifest instead? I want the user to be able to able to perform an action specifically when a user clicks on a download link in a browser.